# How to detect slow web page load and nofity user

Tags: performance

Google and Twitter, just to name a couple, have code in their pages that detects slow page load times, and presents the user with a nice message. I would like to implement something similar, and before I dig in and try to reverse-engineer their implementations, I was wondering if there are any existing components thay may help achieve this goal. (my search-fu failed me)

Thanks!

Comment: just an onload timer will do the job. stop the timer if page loaded completely.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21472452/296430

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen any off the shelf libraries that do this, but isn't it really just loke an AJAX spinner but one that loads after a short delay?