# How to detect slow connection/no connection in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, connection

I need to do the following in angular js app:

When user uses a phone, he might be in a place where the connection is too slow, i want to do a simple popup that behave like this:

If connection is slow/connection is not exist at all for the time, the popup shows, when things come back to normal (there is a response, a good response),  the popup should be removed.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript. This link will be useful for you and you can reuse the logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994061/how-to-detect-slow-internet-connections check this link might help you